# How do I keep the delimiters when splitting a Ruby string?

Tags: ruby

I have text like:

```
content = "Do you like to code? How I love to code! I'm always coding."
```

I'm trying to split it on either a `?` or `.` or `!`:

```
content.split(/[?.!]/)
```

When I print out the results, the punctuation delimiters are missing.

> Do you like to code
>
> How I love to code
>
> I'm always coding

How can I keep the punctuation?

Comment: So you essentially want to put newlines after each delimiter? What is the actual value you want to be returned (in Ruby code)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the implications of that (i.e. putting a newline after each delimiter) are for how I will be presenting the data. Since `split` returns the results in an array, I want the delimiter punctuation included with each sentence in the element of the array so that when I print the elements of the array separately they make sense with the punctuation.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Answer**

Use a positive lookbehind regular expression (i.e. `?<=`) inside a parenthesis capture group to keep the delimiter at the end of each string:

```
content.split(/(?<=[?.!])/)

# Returns an array with:
# ["Do you like to code?", " How I love to code!", " I'm always coding."]
```

That leaves a white space at the start of the second and third strings. Add a match for zero or more white spaces (`\s*`) after the capture group to exclude it:

```
content.split(/(?<=[?.!])\s*/)

# Returns an array with:
# ["Do you like to code?", "How I love to code!", "I'm always coding."]
```

---

**Additional Notes**

While it doesn't make sense with your example, the delimiter can be shifted to the front of the strings starting with the second one. This is done with a positive lookahead regular expression (i.e. `?=`). For the sake of anyone looking for that technique, here's how to do that:

```
content.split(/(?=[?.!])/)

# Returns an array with:
# ["Do you like to code", "? How I love to code", "! I'm always coding", "."]
```

A better example to illustrate the behavior is:

```
content = "- the - quick brown - fox jumps"
content.split(/(?=-)/)

# Returns an array with:
# ["- the ", "- quick brown ", "- fox jumps"]
```

Notice that the square bracket capture group wasn't necessary since there is only one delimiter. Also, since the first match happens at the first character it ends up as the first item in the array.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil check [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Or yet `@content.split(/(?=\?|\.|!)/)`, acording to which part do you want the markers be

Comment: @sawa why is that a "strange requirement"? it seems natural to me. I assume my intention seems obvious, so what would you do?

Comment: It is just subjective. I cannot think of a use. If you are okay with having leading spaces for all sentences but the first one, then that is okay.

Comment: ok, now I understand. I didn't realize the first solution would leave leading spaces. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a brilliant and comprehensive answer to this question. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 20):

To answer the question's title, adding a capture group to your split regex will preserve the split delimiters:

```
"Do you like to code? How I love to code! I'm always coding.".split /([?!.])/
  => ["Do you like to code", "?", " How I love to code", "!", " I'm always coding", "."]
```

From there, it's pretty simple to reconstruct sentences (or do other massaging as the problem calls for it):

```
s.split(/([?!.])/).each_slice(2).map(&:join).map(&:strip)
 => ["Do you like to code?", "How I love to code!", "I'm always coding."]
```

The regexes given in other answers do fulfill the body of the question more succinctly, though.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use something like:

```
content.scan(/.+?[?!.]/)
# => ["Do you like to code?", " How I love to code!", " I'm always coding."]
```

If you want to get rid of the intervening spaces, use:

```
content.scan(/.+?[?!.]/).map(&:lstrip)
# => ["Do you like to code?", "How I love to code!", "I'm always coding."]
```

Comment: You could avoid leading spaces by modifying your regex to `/(?!\s).*?[?.!]/`. Readers: `(?!\s)` is a *negative lookahead* (`?!`) that asserts that the following character is not a whitespace. Regarding the remainder of the regex, `.*` matches all characters other than line terminators. `.*?` does that *lazily*, meaning as few characters as possible are matched. Hence, none of the characters matched are `?`, `.` or `!`. That could alternatively be written `[^?.!\n]*`, meaning "match zero or more characters other than (`^`) the ones in the character class".

Answer (score 9):

Use `partition`. An example from the documentation:

```
"hello".partition("l")         #=> ["he", "l", "lo"]
```

Comment: This only works if there's a single instance of the separator or you only care about the first instance. Per the Ruby docs on `partition`: "Searches sep or pattern (regexp) in the string and returns the part before it, the match, and the part after it. If it is not found, returns two empty strings and str." So `'hellollo'.partition('l')` becomes `["he", "l", "lollo"]`. Use Chris Heald's solution if you want all of them: `'hellollo'.split(/(l)/) # => ["he", "l", "", "l", "o", "l", "", "l", "o"]`

Answer (score 2):

The most robust way to do this is with a Natural Language Processing library: [Rails gem to break a paragraph into series of sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879013/rails-gem-to-break-a-paragraph-into-series-of-sentences)

You can also split in groups:

```
@content.split(/(\?+)|(\.+)|(!+)/)
```

After splitting into groups, you can join the sentence and delimiter.

```
@content.split(/(\?+)|(\.+)|(!+)/).each_slice(2) {|slice| puts slice.join}
```

Comment: Is this not just another way to skin the cat? I don't know what you mean by "The most robust way". One could argue that use of a gem is not warranted when a single line of code can get the job done.