# Count Number of Sentence Ruby

Tags: ruby, count, sentence

I happened to search around everywhere and did not managed to find a solution to count number of sentence in a String using Ruby. Does anyone how to do it?

Example

```
string = "The best things in an artist’s work are so much a matter of intuition, that there is much to be said for the point of view that would altogether discourage intellectual inquiry into artistic phenomena on the part of the artist. Intuitions are shy things and apt to disappear if looked into too closely. And there is undoubtedly a danger that too much knowledge and training may supplant the natural intuitive feeling of a student, leaving only a cold knowledge of the means of expression in its place. For the artist, if he has the right stuff in him ... "
```

This string should return number `4`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18089658/517483 may help.

Comment: How do you define "sentence"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the text into sentences and count them. Here:

```
string.scan(/[^\.!?]+[\.!?]/).map(&:strip).count # scan has regex to split string and strip will remove trailing spaces.
# => 4
```

**Explaining regex:**

```
[^\.!?]
```

Caret inside of a character class `[^ ]` is the negation operator. Which means we are looking for characters which are not present in list: `.`, `!` and `?`.

```
+
```

is a greedy operator that returns matches between 1 and unlimited times. (capturing our sentences here and ignoring repetitions like `...`)

```
[\.!?]
```

matching characters `.`, `!` or `?`.

In a nutshell, we are capturing all characters that are not `.`, `!` or `?` till we  get characters that are `.`, `!` or `?`. Which basically can be treated as a sentence *(in broad senses)*.

Comment: To count elements in array, you actually don't need `.map(&:strip)` here :)

Comment: Could you explain your regular expression? It might not be obvious what it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

I think it makes sense to consider a word char followed by a `?!` or `.` the delimiter of a sentence:

```
string.strip.split(/\w[?!.]/).length
#=> 4
```

So I'm not considering the `...` a delimiter when it hangs on it's own like that:

- "I waited a while ... and then I went home"

But then again, maybe I should...

It also  occurs to me that maybe a better delimiter is a punctuation followed by some space and a capital letter:

```
string.split(/[?!.]\s+[A-Z]/).length
#=> 4
```

Comment: What if there was a Mr. Yule who needed something?

Comment: You could account for that with a lookaround. I'll leave that as an exercise for someone else though.

Answer (score 1):

Sentences end with full stops, question marks, and exclamation marks. They can also be
separated with dashes and other punctuation, but we won’t worry about these rare cases here.
The split is simple. Instead of asking Ruby to split the text on one type of character, you simply
ask it to split on any of three types of characters, like so:

```
txt = "The best things in an artist’s work are so much a matter of intuition, that there is much to be said for the point of view that would altogether discourage intellectual inquiry into artistic phenomena on the part of the artist. Intuitions are shy things and apt to disappear if looked into too closely. And there is undoubtedly a danger that too much knowledge and training may supplant the natural intuitive feeling of a student, leaving only a cold knowledge of the means of expression in its place. For the artist, if he has the right stuff in him ... "

sentence_count = txt.split(/\.|\?|!/).length
puts sentence_count
#=> 7
```

Comment: it produce some extra empty lines, count is 7 for me.

Comment: It is because of the 3 full stops at the end.

Comment: @Mourad I've edited your answer and replaced the return value with the actual one, i.e. `7`

Answer (score 0):

```
string.squeeze('.!?').count('.!?')
  #=> 4
```