# Rails: Split text including dollar end euro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails and Nokogiri and I'm trying to parse some website.
This is where I'm stuck:

```
doc.css('#example > li:nth-child(1)').each do |node|
    money = node.xpath('//*ul/li/div/span').text
end
```

It returns something like:

```
$100,000£230,000$40,000$9,000€600$800,000
```

I want to split those items, save them to the database and finally hand them to the view.

So, in the view, I want it to appear like:

(1)$100,000
(2)£230,000
(3)$40,000
(4)$9,000
(5)€600
(6)$800,000

I tried to split those items by this code below.

```
money = node.xpath('//*ul/li/div/span').text.split(/[$€£]/)
```

but the result looks like this:

```
["", "100,000", "230,000", "40,000", "9,000", "600", "800,000"]
```

And I don't know which item is in Dollar, Euro, or Pond.
Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I keep the delimiters when splitting a Ruby string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089562/how-do-i-keep-the-delimiters-when-splitting-a-ruby-string)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Take note that we now have [ja.so] (Stack Overflowの日本語版).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're almost there,
just use the positive lookahead :)

```
irb(main):005:0> "$100,000£230,000$40,000$9,000€600$800,000".split(/(?=[$£€])/)
=> ["$100,000", "£230,000", "$40,000", "$9,000", "€600", "$800,000"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs a regular expression. This works:

```
"$100,000£230,000$40,000$9,000$600$800,000".scan(/([^\d][0-9,]+)/)

    => [["$100,000"], 
["£230,000"], 
["$40,000"], 
["$9,000"], 
["$600"], 
["$800,000"]]
```

The regex contains these parts:

- `[^\d]`: A character class matching a single non-digit. This will match the currency symbol.
- `[0-9,]+': Another character class, this time repeating (the '+'). It matches the numeric part (0-9) plus the thousand's separator.