# How to split an string containing an arithmetic expression while preserving floating point numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing, math

Given a string containing an arithmetic expression, I need to be able to split the string appropriately so that it separates operators and numbers. The string may or may not contain whitespace. The main obstacle I am facing is how to preserve floats, preserving a negative sign (which could be defined as a - sign between one operator and another digit/number), and separate parentheses from other symbols.

Consider this example:

```
s = "2 / (2 + 3) * 4.75 - -6"
```

I am trying to get this output:

```
["2", "/", "(", "2", "+", "3", ")", "*", "4.75", "-", "-6"]
```

Is it possible to achieve that with regular expressions in Ruby? Or is it more feasible to write a function that parses each character individually?

Comment: The hard  part will be converting `4.33` to `4.75`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Regex is a good approach, something like the following pattern could be
used to extract the floats:

- any number of digits: `\d+`
- a period (optional): `\.?`
- any number of digits (optional). `\d*`

All together now: `/\d+\.?\d*/`

Here's a more complete code example:

```
s = "2 /2+3 * 4.75- -6"
s.gsub(" ", "").split(/(\d+\.?\d*)/).reject(&:empty?)
# => => ["2", "/", "2", "+", "3", "*", "4.75", "--", "6"]
```

A couple things to note here:

- the regex is wrapped in parenthesis (i.e. `/()/`) so that the matched text is
  included in the results array. I actually looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089562/how-do-i-keep-the-delimiters-when-splitting-a-ruby-string)
  to figure out how to do that.
- This solves your problems *except* for the `-` minus sign. You might be able to
  figure this out with some more Regex wrangling, but I think a simpler solution is
  to interpret `--` as a plus sign when it comes time to process the math operators.
- The above regex requires your float strings to have a zero before the decimal point,
  i.e. `0.5` and not just `.5`

In response to your comment, you are correct that this won't separate parenthesis
from operators. It can be updated to do so, though:

Using the same method as above, but with an example string that contains
parentheses:

```
s = "( 2 / 2 ) +3 * 4.75- -6"
new_string = s.gsub(" ", "").split(/(\d+\.?\d*)/).reject(&:empty?)
# => ["(", "2", "/", "2", ")+", "3", "*", "4.75", "--", "6"]
```

Then you could write the following to separate out the parentheses:

```
new_string.map { |str| str.split(/([\(\)])/) }.flatten.reject(&:empty?)
# => ["(", "2", "/", "2", ")", "+", "3", "*", "4.75", "--", "6"]
```

This is an ugly looking regex (aren't they all), but in short:

- wrap the whole regex in parens (i.e. `/()/`) so that `split` includes
  the matched part in the produced array.
- use `[\(\)]` to select *either* a `(` or `)` character.

The use of map & flatten enables you to split each string in your array without
creating sub-arrays.

Comment: Ahhh... That makes sense!

Comment: I just realized though, your solution does not split parentheses from operators. I should have been more specific in my original question.

Answer (score 3):

Regexen are notoriously hard to get right for these types of applications. If you're open to using libraries I'd recommend using an existing tokenizer like [Dentaku](https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku).

```
>> require 'dentaku'
>> tokenizer = Dentaku::Tokenizer.new

>> tokenizer.tokenize("2 /2+3 * 4.75- -6").map(&:raw_value)
=> ["2", "/", "2", "+", "3", "*", "4.75", "-", "-", "6"]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really use libraries, but this is good to know anyways.

Comment: The negative numbers should show up like "-6"  not like "-" and "6"

Answer (score 2):

No need for any library. I think the following regex satisfies the given condition just fine. It shouldn't be a big deal to modify this regex to handle whatever it falls short though.

```
var s = "2 /(2+3) * 4.75- -6",
  rex = /-\d|\d*\.\d+|\d+|[+\-*/()]/g,
  res = [];
res = s.match(rex);
console.log(res); // <- ["2", "/", "(", "2", "+", "3", ")", "*", "4.75", "-", "-6"]
```