# Regex - split mathematic expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm building something called formula builder. The idea is, the user have to type text of formula in `textarea`, then we'll be parse the string value. The result is array.

For example, this text will be parsed

```
LADV-(GCNBIZ+UNIN)+(TNW*-1)
```

then generate result below

```
["LADV", "-", "(", "GCNBIZ", "+", "UNIN", ")", "+", "(", "TNW", "*", "-1", ")"]
```

The point is to split each word joined by one of this character: `+`, `*`, `/`, `-`, `(`, and this `)`; but still include the splitter itself.

I have tried to split using this expression `/[-+*/()]/g`, but the result doesn't include the splitter character. And also the `-1` need to be detected as one expression.

```
["LADV", "MISC", "", "GCNBIZ", "UNIN", "", "", "TNW", "", "1", ""]
```

What is the match regex to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18089658/967478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` instead of `split` with an alternation regex:

```js
var s = 'LADV-(GCNBIZ+UNIN)+(TNW*-1)';

var m = s.match(/(-\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[-+\/*()]|\w+)/g);

console.log(m);

//=> ["LADV", "-", "(", "GCNBIZ", "+", "UNIN", ")", "+", "(", "TNW", "*", "-1", ")"]
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(                   # start capture group
   -                # match a hyphen
   \d+(?:\.\d+)?    # match a number
   |                # OR
   [-+\/*()]        # match one of the symbols
   |                # OR 
   \w+              # match 1 or more word characters
)                   # end capture group
```

Order of patterns in alternation is important.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working and really helpful for me. this one is very detail. but sorry I couldn't accept this as accepted answer because @thomas answering first :-)

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo No. anubhava was the first to answer.

Comment: sorry! my mistake then, I just changed this into accepted answer :-)

Comment: sorry @anubhava, could you help me again? I just found out that some of variable in the formula contains ampersand character `&`. so for example `LADV-A&P` will become `["LADV", "-", "A&P"]`. can you help me? thanks a lot

Comment: sorry for bothering you, but seems like your solution is not working. I tried to use `"LADV-A&P".match(/(-\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[-+\/&*()]|\w+)/g)` but it generate `["LADV", "-", "A", "&", "P"]`. How should I do to make it generate `["LADV", "-", "A&P"]` ? or am I missing something? thanks

Answer (score 2):

```js
var input = 'LADV-(GCNBIZ+UNIN)+(TNW*-1)';
var match = input.match(/(-?\d+)|([a-z]+)|([-+*()\/])/gmi);
console.log(match);
```