# How do I split this string on the 2nd set of a specific pattern?

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following string:

```
 @snippet.diff.body
=> "@@ -1827,7 +1827,7 @@ def has_and_belongs_to_many(name, scope = nil, **options, &extension)\n \n           builder = Builder::HasAndBelongsToMany.new name, self, options\n \n-          join_model = builder.through_model\n+          join_model = ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { builder.through_model }\n \n           const_set join_model.name, join_model\n           private_constant join_model.name\n
@@ -1856,7 +1856,7 @@ def destroy_associations\n             hm_options[k] = options[k] if options.key? k\n           end\n \n-          has_many name, scope, hm_options, &extension\n+          ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { has_many name, scope, hm_options, &extension }\n           _reflections[name.to_s].parent_reflection = habtm_reflection\n         end\n       end"
```

Basically, I want to split this string from the first 'special section' to the second special section, where a 'special section' (or a substring) can be identified by some string that looks like this: `@@ -1856,7 +1856,7 @@`

So using the above string, I would like to have this:

```
string1 = "@@ -1827,7 +1827,7 @@ def has_and_belongs_to_many(name, scope = nil, **options, &extension)\n \n           builder = Builder::HasAndBelongsToMany.new name, self, options\n \n-          join_model = builder.through_model\n+          join_model = ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { builder.through_model }\n \n           const_set join_model.name, join_model\n           private_constant join_model.name\n"

string2 = "@@ -1856,7 +1856,7 @@ def destroy_associations\n             hm_options[k] = options[k] if options.key? k\n           end\n \n-          has_many name, scope, hm_options, &extension\n+          ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { has_many name, scope, hm_options, &extension }\n           _reflections[name.to_s].parent_reflection = habtm_reflection\n         end\n       end"
```

Note that the numbers between the `@@` aren't always the same....the key thing is there will be some substring between two sets of `@@` that mark the beginning of this string. Then the other set marks the end of this one, and the beginning of the next string.

Comment: Something like `str.scan(/^@@.+@@[^@@]+/)` may help.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 As far as I understand, `[^@@]` is just `[^@]`. So it won't work if the displayed code has instance variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## With split and positive lookahead

You could just split at every line beginning with @@:

```
body.split(/(?=^@@)/)
```

You need a [lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18089658/6419007) to keep `@@` in the string : that way, the original strings gets split at the beginning of a line, right before `@@`.

## With split and slice_before

You could split on every line and slice before a `/@@../` :

```
body = "@@ -1827,7 +1827,7 @@ def has_and_belongs_to_many(name, scope = nil, **options, &extension)\n \n           builder = Builder::HasAndBelongsToMany.new name, self, options\n \n-          join_model = builder.through_model\n+          join_model = ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { builder.through_model }\n \n           const_set join_model.name, join_model\n           private_constant join_model.name\n
@@ -1856,7 +1856,7 @@ def destroy_associations\n             hm_options[k] = options[k] if options.key? k\n           end\n \n-          has_many name, scope, hm_options, &extension\n+          ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { has_many name, scope, hm_options, &extension }\n           _reflections[name.to_s].parent_reflection = habtm_reflection\n         end\n       end"

body.each_line.slice_before(/^@@[\d\+\-, ]+@@/).map(&:join)
```

Both methods return an array of 2 strings with your example. The second one might be more robust than the first one.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without splitting at the newline and then reconstructing the string after? That feels like unnecessary work.

Comment: @marcamillion: Updated. See the first variant.

Comment: Perfect...that first one works perfectly. Can you add a simply explanation for how it does, what it does please? Just for completeness sake. In other words, does `?=^` limit the regex to just look for the pattern that follows these characters at the beginning of each line?

Comment: marcamillion, recall that lookarounds (here the positive lookahead `(?=^@@)`) are *zero-width*, meaning that they capture no characters. In effect, this regex divides the string at a location *between* two characters, that location being immediately before `^@@...`. Splitting on a lookaround has a multitude of applications. For example "xxxxx".split(/(?=xxx)/) #=> ["x", "x", "xxx"]`.