# MailGun: Stored Message API: How to separate forwarded email from original email?

Tags: mailgun

i'm using mailgun ROUTING to `post` emails into my app when received at `xyz@ouremail.myapp.com`.

Similar to the [Retrieving Stored Messages] API.(https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages)

The documentation says:

> **Note:** Do not rely on the `body-plain`, `stripped-text`, and `stripped-signature` fields for HTML sanitization. These fields merely provide content from the text/plain portion of an incoming message. This content may contain unescaped HTML.

I have been using `bod-plain` to retrieve the thread, but it includes the entire email thread without separation context.

I'm like to show a single message. There's no documentation for recommended parsing and separating the thread into multiple messages.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found that all forwarded messaged have retained headers, and thus start with `From:`.

Using Regexp I have been able to split the thread into multiple messages.

`email_body.split(/(?=From:)/)`

The [positive lookbehind regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18089658/1536309)  allows me to keep the delimiter in the split up chunks.