# Listening to HTTP Json stream triggers JSON:ParserError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, string, parsing

My Rails project is listening to a text/json type HTTP stream – It normally works fine until about an hour in, and then the API seems to send two objects at once and it triggers a `JSON::ParserError`, most likely due to the API (I have no control over it) sending two JSON objects at once without a comma.

I'd like to know if there's some sort of check (possibly regex?) I can include to make sure the input strings that get fed into JSON.parse() are all valid JSON objects without causing any sort of performance issues – I'd like to pass every JSON object that the API emits into JSON.parse() without having to skip any due to the API sending them not separated by commas if possible.

My code for the rails job that performs the parsing and saves the parsed json object as an ActiveRecord object (Variable names have been changed from the originals and I might have used ruby keywords or something so I apologize if I made it confusing.)

```
  def perform(*args)
    # Do something later
    puts "Listener Started!"

    response = HTTP.get("https://example.com/stream")
    response.body.each do |piece|
      parsed = piece && piece.length >= 2 ? JSON.parse(piece) : nil
      if parsed
        thing = Thing.find_or_create_by(id: parsed["uuid"]) do |thing|
          thing.content = parsed["content"]
          thing.created_at = parsed["created_at"]
          thing.amount = parsed["amount"]
          thing.variety = parsed["variety"]
        end
        expense.employee = Author.find_or_create_by(id: parsed["author"]["uuid"]) do |author|
          author.first_name = parsed["author"]["first_name"]
          author.last_name = parsed["author"]["last_name"]
        end
        thing.save
      end
    end
  end
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Error performing ListenForExpenseJob (Job ID: 4b275dc3-4234-4249-8dc5-186ac02fc424) from Async(default) in 2826495.7ms:

JSON::ParserError (784: unexpected token at 
'{"uuid": "ea065b39-68d7-4abb-bb44-04f3006ad2bb", "content": "Impedit aut amet ea quisquam culpa saepe.", "created_at": "2019-10-13T02:16:53", "amount": 654, "variety": "OMR", "author": {"uuid": "910e81b1-afd1-4a04-9fc5-ff644abc5a96", "first_name": "Jenny", "last_name": "Person"}}
{"uuid": "f2981a04-4699-476e-86ed-d83999428045", "description": "Debitis libero voluptas quidem deleniti facilis.", "created_at": "2019-10-05T22:17:09", "amount": 6381, "variety": "BRL", "author": {"uuid": "a73e2de8-abf2-4e99-8e3b-e3fb72d0b3ba", "first_name": "Jacob", "last_name": "Human"}}
'):
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what will happen given the code you've shown and the input you receive. [Do you have a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'd like to know if there's some sort of check (possibly regex?) I can include to make sure the input strings that get fed into `JSON.parse()` are all valid JSON objects without causing any sort of performance issues – I'd like to pass every JSON object that the API emits into JSON.parse() without having to skip any due to the API sending them not separated by commas if possible.

Comment: Would it be best to add that comment into the original post? I'm somewhat new to asking questions here and assumed that "I get this error" implies that I don't want the error to show up.

Comment: Yes, your question should include a question. Don't expect us to guess at your question. You could have been asking "Is this what should happen?" or "How do I fix the remote API?" or "How do I ignore malformed records?" or "How do I accept the first record and skip the second record?" or any number of other things. Please read the article I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the malformed records are always **exactly** as you have described here, then a simple if naive solution might be:

```
piece = <<EOF
{"uuid": "ea065b39-68d7-4abb-bb44-04f3006ad2bb", "content": "Impedit aut amet ea quisquam culpa saepe.", "created_at": "2019-10-13T02:16:53", "amount": 654, "variety": "OMR", "author": {"uuid": "910e81b1-afd1-4a04-9fc5-ff644abc5a96", "first_name": "Jenny", "last_name": "Person"}}
{"uuid": "f2981a04-4699-476e-86ed-d83999428045", "description": "Debitis libero voluptas quidem deleniti facilis.", "created_at": "2019-10-05T22:17:09", "amount": 6381, "variety": "BRL", "author": {"uuid": "a73e2de8-abf2-4e99-8e3b-e3fb72d0b3ba", "first_name": "Jacob", "last_name": "Human"}}
EOF

piece = piece.gsub("\n", '').gsub(/}{/, '},{').prepend('[').concat(']')
parsed = JSON.parse(piece)
parsed.each do |parsed_piece|
  # do something to validate and save parsed piece
end
```

This will work for any number of records that are sent at once by removing newlines, separating the records with commas, turning the whole string into a JSON array, parsing the JSON array, and then iterating over the array elements.

You can probably [get clever with `.split()` or `.scan()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18089562/3784008) to look for `}{` and chunk the string into an array based on that element, then run `JSON.parse` on each array element, and *then* iterate over the array to do some validation and saving, for example:

```
pieces = piece.gsub("\n", '').split(/(}{)/)
new_pieces = []
pieces.each_with_index do |piece, index|
  if pieces.length == 1
    new_pieces << piece
  elsif index.zero?
    new_pieces << "#{piece}#{pieces[index + 1][0]}"
  elsif index.even?
    new_piece = "#{pieces[index - 1][1]}#{piece}"
    new_piece = "#{new_piece}#{pieces[index - 1][0]}" unless index == pieces.length - 1
    new_pieces << new_piece
  end
end
new_pieces.map { |piece| JSON.parse(piece) }
```

And you can probably make that block a little simpler with some of the aforementioned cleverness.