# How do I get Ruby's String Split Method to Include Newlines in the Output?

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-1.9.2

There's this code right here:

```
thing = "Stuff.\nHello!"
result = thing.split(" ")
# ^Is equal to ["Stuff.", "Hello!"] despite the delimiter being a single space instead of a newline
```

How do I make it so that the newline is included, making the result var equal to ["Stuff.\n", "Hello!"] instead?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2. For those who are curious, I need to know this for the sake of a word-wrapping algorithm that replaces line-break tags with newlines.

Comment: Why do you use a Ruby version that was released more than 12 years ago and reached end of life about 8 years ago and got no bug fixes and security updates for ages?

Comment: See the following about retaining delimiters when splitting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089562/how-do-i-keep-the-delimiters-when-splitting-a-ruby-string

Comment: @spickermann A few clients of mine want me to work on a word-wrapping algorithm for RPG Maker VX Ace, which itself uses Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: @steenslag Oof, can't believe I got arrays and strings confused ^^;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regexp with a [positive look-behind assertion](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors):

```
thing = "Stuff.\nHello!"
thing.split(/(?<=\s)/)
#=> ["Stuff.\n", "Hello!"]
```

The positive look-behind assertion `(?<=pat)` ensures that the preceding characters match `pat`, but doesn’t include those characters in the matched text.

Answer (score 4):

One could simply use [String#lines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-lines).

```
"Stuff.\nHello!".lines    #=> ["Stuff.\n", "Hello!"]
```

```
"Stuff.\nHello!\n".lines  #=> ["Stuff.\n", "Hello!\n"]
```