# How to capitalize first character of each sentence in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a model `Question`, it has two fields `question:text` and `description:text`. i want to capitalize first character of each sentence of both fields by using `before_save` callback. what is the best way to do it? Thanks

**This question is different than marked as duplicate one because that answer is for only ruby code but my question gives the answer for rails code and it helps the beginners to understand the logic.**

How do i make it DRY?

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :capitalize_values

  def capitalize_values
    self.question = question.split('.').map(&:strip).map { |s|
                      s[0].upcase + s[1..-1] + '.'
                    }.join(' ')  unless question.blank?
    self.description = description.split('.').map(&:strip).map { |s| 
                         s[0].upcase + s[1..-1] + '.'
                       }.join(' ') unless description.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: but i need to know, how i can do it in rails model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :capitalize_attributes

  def capitalize_attributes
    self.question = capitalize_sentences(question)
    self.description = capitalize_sentences(description)
  end

  def capitalize_sentences(string)
    unless string.blank?
      string.split('.').map do |sentence|
        sentence.strip.capitalize
      end.join(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Above answer applies capitalization on only first sentence and if input has more than one sentence than other sentences first char doesnt capitalize.

Comment: Thank you but can you plz have a look at the question and let me know, how to DRY the code. i ll be grateful :)

Comment: @Murtza, I just updated my answer to DRY up the capitalization code

Answer (score 1):

Splitting a string into individual sentences is not a trivial task, described here: [rails-gem-to-break-a-paragraph-into-series-of-sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879013/rails-gem-to-break-a-paragraph-into-series-of-sentences)

If you don't mind a naive approximation, you could also use:

```
split(/(?<=[?.!])/)
```

So after that you can DRY it up like this:

```
[:question, :description].each do |atr|
  value = send(a).split(/(?<=[?.!])/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
  send("#{a}=", value)
end
```

Instead of `send` you could use `read_attribute`/`write_attribute`, look here for the difference: [set-attributes-in-activerecord](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/)